# Render background image pixelated css

Tags: html, css

I have got a little issue, here is my code.

```css
img {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

div.fight {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/yM1ts8x.png");
  background-size: contain;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

div.fight img.player {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 4%;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fight">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VJhdtWy.png" class="player">
</div>
```

You can see code in action here http://jsfiddle.net/ctwgkodp/11/. (Excuse me for ugly pixel art)

As you can see in `img`, I set that all images in my app are rendered pixelated. The problem is that when I set `background`, I cannot force it to be pixelated.

Is there any way to force pixelated render to `background` of `div.fight`?

Thank you and have a nice day. :)

Comment: That pixel art is sick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are only applying the `image-rendering: pixelated` to the `img` tag. You also need to apply it to the `.fight` div:

```css
img {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
div.fight{
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/yM1ts8x.png");
  background-size: contain;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
div.fight img.player{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 4%;
  height: 64px; 
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fight">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VJhdtWy.png" class="player">
</div>
```

In fact you can remove the `image-rendering` from the `img` entirely since it will be inherited from the parent `div`.

```css
div.fight{
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/yM1ts8x.png");
  background-size: contain;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
div.fight img.player{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 4%;
  height: 64px; 
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fight">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VJhdtWy.png" class="player">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god, it was that simple? :O